# Save SpooledTemporaryFile on disk

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, pdf, temporary-files

I need a function like:

storepdf(pdf, path)

pdf is a SpooledTemporaryFile (was a pdf before processing) and path the path, where I want to save this file as .pdf in directory.

How can I do this?

Answer (score -2):

Okay I used PyPDF2, read the tempfile and wrote it into a new created Pdf, that worked for me.